# unix db2 BIGINT Vs Decimal as primary key

Tags: db2

Need suggestion on which Datatype would give better performance if we set one of these as primary key in DB2 - BIGINT or Decimal(13,0) type?

I suspect Decimal(13,0) will have issues once the key grows to a very big size but I wanted a better answer/understanding for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimal does not have issues. The only thing, is that DB2 has to do more operations to retrieve the data, once is read. I mean, DB2 read the data and then it should find the decimal part (the precision) even if is 0.

On the other hand, DB2 will read the BigInt and it does not need any further process. The number is on the bufferpool.

If you are going to use integers of 13 positions (most of them), probably Decimal will be better because you are not going to use extra bytes, however decimals have extra bytes for the precision. By using decimal in this way, you are going to optimize the storage, and this will be translated in better IO, better performance. However, it depends on the other columns of your table. You have to test which of them gives you better performance.

When using compression, there are more CPU cycles to recover the information. You have to test if the performance is affected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BIGINT`:

- Can store ~19 digits (versus 13)
- *Will* take 8 bytes (versus maybe either 7 or 13 - see next)
- Depending on platform, `DECIMAL` will be stored as a form of [Binary Coded Decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) - for example, on the iSeries (and I can't remember if it's Packed or Zoned).  Can't speak to other deployments, unfortunately.
- You aren't doing *math* on these values (things like "next entry" don't count) - save `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC` for measurements/values.

Note that, really, ids are just a sequence of bits - the fact that it **happens** to be an integer (usually) is irrelevant.  It's best to consider them random data; sequential assignment is an optimization detail, there's often gaps (rollbacks, system crashes, whatever), and they're meaningless for anything other than joining.